# MeanJS user management

Tags: node.js, meanjs

I am using the mean.js stack.  I want to manage my list of users, but there is no apparent solution for this.  Is there an admin module for meanjs available that allows crud functions on the user database? If not please point me to a jsfiddle that shows how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

[MEAN.js 0.4.1](https://github.com/meanjs/mean) has an admin module built in which allows a user with admin privileges to perform user management.

If you are currently using an older version maybe try to look at the code there and make the necessary changes to implement a similar module.

Answer (score 0):

the other answer is correct, meanjs.org 0.4x already has this feature built in.

While for 0.3x and below you need to manually create one. It shouldn't be hard, just a regular CRUD but for users model.